# How can I connect to redis using php but without use a client library

Tags: php, redis

I'd like know what is the way to connect to redis using php from scratch (without use a client like predis)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can connect by using `fsockopen` and communicate by sending raw commands and reading server response:

```
$c = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 6379, $errCode, $errStr);

$rawCommand = "*2\r\n\$4\r\nEcho\r\n\$12\r\nhello world!\r\n";

fwrite($c, $rawCommand);

$rawResponse = fgets($c);
echo $rawResponse; // $12

$rawResponse = fgets($c);
echo $rawResponse; // hello world!
```

To use it this way, you should get familiar with Redis protocol: http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Comment: Is there any library in PHP that does converts the command for eg `RPUSH mylist "one"` into RESP compatible string?

Answer (score 1):

Using a raw TCP connection is one way.

You could easily reference the Predis code to see how they connect.

[https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.7/lib/Predis/Network/StreamConnection.php::tcpStreamInitializer()](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.7/lib/Predis/Network/StreamConnection.php#L70)

And that is basically a wrapper for http://php.net/stream_socket_client : So I would reference that page for the most verbose info.

If I am not mistaken, it would be the same as making a TELNET connection in the command line and interfacing with Redis in that manner.

Hope that helps.